# Prove the limit related to a recurrence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

For the following sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, we define $a_1=\alpha\in(0,1)$, and for any $n\geq 2$, $a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_n)$.

Prove: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{na_n} = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

- Prove that $(a_n)$ is decreasing sequence bounded below by $0$ so it's convergent to $0$
- Prove that
  $$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_{n}}\sim 1$$
- Use the Cesaro theorem to find the desired result.

Comment: $.5,.45,.445,.4445,\dots$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by zero --- so, it's convergent to zero?

Comment: If in fact it is possible to prove the limit of the sequence exists, say it is $\;A\;$,  then by arithmetic of limits we'd get $$A=A(1-A)\implies A=0$$ but the first point, as it is, is wrong.