# Given $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n)$, find $\lim_{n \to \infty}n.x_{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequence-of-function

> Let the sequence $\{x_n\}$ be such that $0<x_{1}<1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_{n}\left(1-x_{n}\right)$. Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n.x_{n}$

So far I have only been able to prove that the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

I tried finding $x_2,x_3,..$ in terms of $x_1$ but they didnt seem to form a pattern(i.e. I couldnt find $x_n$ explicitly in terms of $x_1$)

Any hint in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/531552/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2872830/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034255/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/759100/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2052351/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3Dx_%7Bn%7D%5Cleft(1-x_%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I swear I checked for duplicates with both approach0 and MSE search. I didnt find any!